# Application running as x86 or x64?

Tags: x86, 64-bit, windows-server-2008-x64

One of my applications is crashing and I am told that this could be because it is running as an x64 process when it should be running as x86. The  targeting CPU is the default “Any CPU”, instead of being “x86” (which it should be if this is the problem) in Compile configuration. My question is this, in task manager it shows the process for my application like this **myService.exe *32**. Which suggests to me that it is running as 32 bit, but in the **WERC92F.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml** file I get when it crashes it has the following lines:

```
<Flavor>Multiprocessor Free</Flavor>
    <Architecture>X64</Architecture>
```

Why is this saying x64?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

X64 is in this case the operating systems architecture, not the process model in use.